# My firebase Create User trigger 2 times instead of one

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-hook-form, react-functional-component

Creating a react app usign `react-firebase-hook`,`firebase`,`react-hook-form`,`daisyUI`
The problem is When I am pressing submit button it triggers 2 times in the console and when using the Button; `Sign Up With Google` it triggers 3times.Thanks for your time in advance.

In SingUP function:

```
import auth from '../../firebase.init';
import { useSignInWithGoogle } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';

function SignUp() {
  const [signInWihGoogle, googleUser, googleLoading, googleError] = useSignInWithGoogle(auth);
  const { register, formState: { errors }, handleSubmit } = useForm();

  const [
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
    user,
    loading,
    error,
  ] = useCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth);
```

This function is triggering:

```
  const onSubmit = data =>{
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(data.email,data.password);
    alert('You successfully created your account');
  }
```

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>


          <div class="form-control w-full max-w-xs">
              <label class="label">
                <span class="label-text">Name</span>
              </label>
              <input 
              type="text" 
              placeholder="Pls type name here" 
              class="input input-bordered w-full max-w-xs"
              {...register("name", {
                        required:{
                          value: true,
                          message:'Name is Required'
                        },
                        minLength: {
                          value:2,
                          message:'Name must be 2 or more characters
                        }
                      })}/>
             
            </div>
                ... .... ...
              <input 
                type='submit' 
                value= 'Signup'
                class="btn w-full max-w-xs text-white"/>
             </form>
        <p className='text-center text-xs pt-1'>Already have an account?<Link 
        className='text-secondary' to='/login'> Please Login</Link></p>

        <div class="divider">OR</div>
           <button 
            onClick={() => signInWihGoogle()}
            class="btn btn-outline">Continue with Google</button>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you still have the strict mode tag in your App?
If so: delete it and if you want you can read more on it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html

Comment: Thanks, Mikka. It was in strict mode and is now deleted and it works fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).